# C# .NET5 Single File Application Read and Parse Json / Txt or other file formats from directory

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-5, txt

I am reading files on .NET Framework like this:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"sources\settings.json";
string jsonResult = File.ReadAllText(path);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(jsonResult);
```

When I switch to .NET5 this only works on Debug mode. When I create a `Single File Executable` using **Publish** it is not running. When U click the Exe it never open or throws an exception. Also, `try-catch` block couldn't handle the exception.

Publish settings:
[image: publish settings]

How can I make this work on .NET5 Single Exe files?

Comment: *this fails* - please always be more descriptive when asking other programmers for help. Exact error messages please

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard I added more description and added publish settings ss. There is no error message, that's the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` instead of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static Settings LoadSettingsFile()
{
  string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  string directoryPath = @$"{currentPath}\sources";
  string path = @$"{directoryPath}\settings.json";

  string jsonResult = File.ReadAllText(path);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(jsonResult);
}
```

If you are reading a JSON file then, you can parse it to your class with Newtonsoft. This works for txt or other file formats too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting settings.json file which resides along with your exe location. Then you can simply use

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static Settings ReadConfig()
{
  string path = @$"settings.json";
  string settingsText = File.ReadAllText(path);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(settingsText);
}
```

Another methord is to use **ExpressSettings** NugGet.

*It's a very simple library I created to read and write settings in .NET.
You can read and write settings in one line of code.*

It's available for .NET Framework and .NET Core.
If you think it's usefull you can use here : https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/Express-Settings