# How to deserialize JSON file to C# object by section

Tags: c#, json

I have 2 C# class:

```
public class Light
{
    public int Brightness { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}

public class AirConditioner
{
    public int Temperature{ get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}
```

JSON file format:

```
{
  "Light": {
    "Brightness": 5,
    "Mode": "On"
  },
  "AirConditioner": {
    "Temperature": 25,
    "Mode": "Cooling"
  }
}
```

I want to parse JSON file to C# by section, something like this:

```
var light = JsonDeserialize<Light>.(FileSection["Light"]);
var aircon = JsonDeserialize<AirConditioner>.(FileSection["AirConditioner"]);
```

What I want is the same as Asp.Net Core configuration work:

```
var light = new Light();
Configuration.GetSection("Light").Bind(light);
```

It will be better if I do not need to install other packages.

### Thank you for your help.

Update:
The problem is how to get a section of the JSON file.
If I can get the *Light* section like this:

```
var lightString = JsonFile.GetSection("Light");
```

Then I can simply deserialize with *System.Text.Json* namespace:

```
var light = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Light>(lightString);
```

Comment: You may try Newtonsoft: using Newtonsoft.Json; var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Light>(FileSection["Light"]);

Comment: You may also read JSON file from the folder like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102873/c-sharp-net5-single-file-application-read-and-parse-json-txt-or-other-file-fo/67102874#67102874

Comment: Cannot deserialize without definding new class. The problem is how to get the "Light" section to string.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a parent class that holds the Light and AirConditioner properties.

The parent Class:

```
public class Devices
{
    public Light Light {get;set;}
    public AirConditioner AirConditioner {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can de-serialize into the Devices and access the light and airconditioner.

```
var devices = JsonDeserialize<Devices>.(myjsonfilecontent);
var light = devices.Light;
var aircon = devices.AirConditioner;
```

Comment: I thought about your method but it is needed to define new class.

Comment: @NamPham, New class is a simple copy past. in visual studio you have special past that does that for you. It's a no cost. there is a ton a free online tool that will do that too : https://app.quicktype.io, with a simple past of your json

Comment: Any implementation will require parsing the entire JSON string.  Selecting the property will not stop that from happening.  If you do want that behavior @moreON mentioned in the other answer a good source that has some helper methods to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm in Newtonsoft's JSON.Net

It allows for manipulating of a whole JSON object as very generic `JOBject` and locating and converting only the parts you need.

In your example this looks something like the following. This code uses the `newtonsoft.json` package.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace SO_67293726
{

    public class Light
    {
        public int Brightness { get; set; }
        public string Mode { get; set; }
    }

    public class AirConditioner
    {
        public int Temperature { get; set; }
        public string Mode { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static string JsonString =>
@"{
  ""Light"": {
    ""Brightness"": 5,
    ""Mode"": ""On""
  },
  ""AirConditioner"": {
    ""Temperature"": 25,
    ""Mode"": ""Cooling""
  }
}";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jobject = JObject.Parse(JsonString);
            var light = jobject["Light"].ToObject<Light>();
            var aircon = jobject["AirConditioner"].ToObject<AirConditioner>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that doing this simply as part of `System.Text.Json` is still an open issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274 . An existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138793/system-text-json-jsonelement-toobject-workaround may help if you're committed to avoiding newtonsoft.json

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is really what I am looking for. Although I need to install Newtonsoft.Json package. Waiting for dotnet support this feature.